# Azure DNS - How to create MB and RP records?

Tags: azure, dns

I'm migrating all my DNS services to Azure DNS. I have one DNS zone left. It has 2 records I cannot create on Azure DNS - the options are just not there.

It's a Responsible Person (RP)-record and a Mailbox (MB)-record

How can I create these records and move this last zone to Azure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, Azure DNS does not support RP and MB records and that's why you don't see the ability to create these records. From [`Azure DNS Documentation`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/dns-getstarted-create-recordset-portal/):

> Azure DNS supports all common DNS record types, including **A, AAAA,
>   CNAME, MX, NS, SOA, SRV, and TXT**. SOA record sets are created
>   automatically with each zone. They cannot be created separately. Note
>   that SPF records should be created by using the TXT record type.

My guess is that you would need to wait for Azure DNS to support these record types.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. It's just the one zone out of 300 and I hope to find a way to get rid of it, not keep alive a full server for this one.